# I have a 256GB Macbook Pro but only shows 142gb of storage

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, storage

I have a 256GB Mac book pro but it only shows that I have 142GB of storage. on a macbook pro 2017 13 inch w/touchbar and my OS X is 10.14

`Diskutil List` shows the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         142.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +142.0 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            70.7 GB    disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 47.0 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Any help?

Comment: which Mac what OS X

Comment: I have the macbook pro 2017 13 inch w/touchbar and my OS X is 10.14

Comment: to confirm, take look at About this Mac > Storage > Manage

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kG1fx2c

Comment: Thank you (it confirms 142GB), .....was it always like that or only after Mojave upgrade ?

Comment: you could try to resize the APFS assuming you have no other partition https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/resize-your-apfs-container/  ... PLEASE BACK UP FIRST !!!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the remaining space is not partitioned.

Get a good backup since an erase and reinstall should fix things.

Before you erase, boot to recovery HD and try to repair the Macintosh HD and also repair the drive itself.

Comment: How should I do that?